# Simplify nested sums - on the road of a stochastic problem (mixed replacement / kinda non-replacement)

Tags: stochastic-processes

In short, the expression I want to simplify is the following:

$$ P(l) = \frac{P_0}{n^l} * \left(\sum_{p_l=1}^k p_l \sum_{p_{l-1}=p_l}^k p_{l-1} ... \sum_{p_1=p_2}^k p_1 \right) $$

or eventually easier notated:

$$ P(l) = \frac{P_0}{n^l} * \left(\sum_{1 \leq p_l \leq p_{l-1} \leq ... \leq p_1 \leq k} p_l \cdot p_{l-1} \cdot ... \cdot p_1\right) $$

Where $P_0 = P(l=0)$.

#### The problem at hand:

I have a process which draws $k$ random numbers out of $n$ possible numbers in total. If a drawn number was already drawn - let's denote this event as $\bar{X}$ - it will be ignored and we will just draw a new random number. If the drawn number was not already drawn - let's call this $X$ - the number is memorized (stored in a cache). We draw numbers until we have $k$ different numbers.

Diggin into this problem I realized it is kind of mixed replacement/non-replacement but not exactly. It is with replacement in case of drawing a doubled number ($\bar{X}$). But when drawing a unique number ($X$) we are not taking it out of the pool of $n$ total numbers. Therefore, only the numerator changes but not the denominator.

Initially, we have no numbers drawn, i.e. $P(\bar{X}) = 0$. We will ignore this first trivial step. That means for the first step in this problem we consider $P(X) = \frac{n-1}{n}$ and $P(\bar{X}) = \frac{1}{n}$. The second step then has probabilities:

$$
P_{\bar{X}}(\bar{X}) = \frac{1}{n},\quad
P_{\bar{X}}(X) = \frac{n-1}{n},\quad
P_{X}(\bar{X}) = \frac{2}{n},\quad
P_{X}(X) = \frac{n-2}{n}
$$

For a hopefully better understanding I added a [probability tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yle2C.jpg).

Now we can take a look e.g. at the probability of - when drawing $k$ numbers - that we have drawn $l$ duplicate numbers. I.e. we hitted $\bar{X}$ $l$ times. This probability $P(l)$ is fairly easy for the cases $l=0$ and $l=1$. But when trying to generalize it gets a bit cumbersome.

What we can see is that no matter which path we choose we get exactly the same factors as for $P(l=0)$ (which corresponds to the fact that we need to draw $X$ exactly $k$ times) plus $l$ factors for drawing $l$ times $\bar{X}$. One eventually come up with:

$$
P(l) = P_0 * \left(\sum_{p_l=1}^k \frac{p_l}{n} \sum_{p_{l-1}=p_l}^k \frac{p_{l-1}}{n} ... \sum_{p_1=p_2}^k \frac{p_1}{n} \right)
    = \frac{P_0}{n^l} * \left(\sum_{p_l=1}^k p_l \sum_{p_{l-1}=p_l}^k p_{l-1} ... \sum_{p_1=p_2}^k p_1 \right)
$$

and

$$
P_0 = P(l=0) = \prod_{p=0}^k \frac{n-p}{n} = \frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!n^{k+1}}
$$

#### What I've tried

I tried to be super smart and thought by looking at the sum for $l=2$ that it is kinda like a triangle. So I tried something like:

$$
P(l) = \frac{P_0}{n^l} * \left(\sum_{p_l=1}^k p_l \sum_{p_{l-1}=p_l}^k p_{l-1} ... \sum_{p_1=p_2}^k p_1 \right) \overset{?}{=} \frac{P_0}{2n^l} * \left(\left(\sum_{p=1}^k p \right)^l + \sum_{q=1}^k q^l \right)
$$

The idea was that terms like $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot ... \cdot 3$ are always present twice (as a mirrored variance) in the first sum of my approach. Such that we can cut the sum by half and we're fine. But looking further at it one may realize that this approach counts way too much. Namely all terms which are not monotonous increasing or decreasing. E.g. terms like $1 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 \cdot ... \cdot 3$. Those are not covered by just cutting it by half. In fact, if you investigate this as function of $l$ you will find that it diverges for large $l$ which is of course non-sense.

I also tried to do some index shifting to use the gaussian summation but soon I realized that I'd not get anywhere soon with this mess:

$$
P(l) = \frac{P_0}{n^l} * \left(\sum_{p_l=1}^k p_l \sum_{p_{l-1}=p_l}^k p_{l-1} ... \sum_{p_1=0}^{k-p_2} (p_1 + p_2) \right) = \frac{P_0}{n^l} * \left(\sum_{p_l=1}^k p_l \sum_{p_{l-1}=p_l}^k p_{l-1} ... (k - p_2 + 1) \frac{k+p_2}{2} \right)
$$

#### What I'm hoping for

I kinda feel like that my type of problem is not new to the world. So I would be really happy if there was some work of other people I wasn't able to find. But if you have a clever idea to simplify this nested sum I would be very happy too.

Thanks in advance to anyone who had the patience to read all of this :)

Comment: What you describe seems to be the simple model for drawing without replacement. But what is the interpretation of the probability $P(\ell)$? Maybe this probability is well known.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!
As I stated: I draw $k$ random number from a pool of $n$ numbers. If I get duplicates they "get back into the urn" so this part is with replacement. When hitting a new one the number does not get removed from "the urn" so this part is not exactly like "without replacement". $P(l)$ is the probability of finding $k$ different numbers with exactly $l$ duplicates drawn in the path (i.e. rerolls).